# Excel Code Editor doesn't work (blank window)

Tags: excel, typescript

I'm having an issue with Excel Code editor. From time to time it crashes and only shows white window.
Do you know what might be an issue?  I was able to fix it once, by relogging to Microsoft account everywhere, but it's pretty annoying.

[image: screenshot]